# Dark vertical line on a panorama control background image edge in Windows Phone

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, rendering, windows-phone-7.1, panorama-control

I set a panorama backgroundBrush the following way:

In DataContext:

```
var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri("../Images/panorama.background.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
var backBrush = new ImageBrush { ImageSource = bitmapImage };
PanoramaBackgroundBrush = backBrush;
```

In View:

```
<controls:Panorama Background="{Binding PanoramaBackgroundBrush}"
```

The `panorama.background.png` is a white image with an app logo on top.

Whenever I scroll over the edge of Panorama background (from last panorama item to the first one), a vertical thin dark line appears at a time of motion. When the transition stops, the line disappears.

You can see the problem on a video of a simulator I have [uploaded to youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2udvJgJLoUg).

It is almost as if the rendering engine of WP SL is not catching up to redraw the transition of the image's edge. But the same background is in the Office Hub, and it doesn't have a problem I am experiencing.

Please advise on how to solve the vertical line problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can reproduce this and sometimes even got bigger gaps while testing.

I think the office hub suffers from the same problem but is faking it away by using a white background. And you can do so, too:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
```

This gives the grid *behind* the `Panorama` a white background. If your image is white at the edge (like in the YouTube video) then the glitch won't be visible anymore.

Comment: I've been setting the Page's background and it wasn't working for some reason. With the Grid it works. Thank you.